# How getchar() is implemented?

Tags: c, stdio

I was just wondering how [`getchar()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) is implemented? Is it something like the following? It is quite inefficient to read this way, single byte. Does it use some buffering?

**Pseudo code:**

```
int getchar() {

    char buf[1];
    int n = read(0, buf, 1);

    if(n < 1)
        printf("Read failed");

    return buf[0];
}
```

Comment: The existence of `ungetc()` should confirm that it needs to use buffering of *some* kind.

Comment: There are plenty of implementations for you to look at, merely a google search away.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the number of implementations for the standard C library, it's not possible to provide a definite answer, but the most common ones seem to follow the same general guidelines.

By definition, `getchar()` uses the stream infrastructure of the standard C library i.e. `FILE` and its friendly functions. In most modern C library implementations, the file streams are buffered to a degree, with the buffer size and behavior usually being tunable via [`setvbuf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf).

I am aware of at least one case ([glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)) where files may optionally - via an extra option to `fopen()` - be accessed via memory mapping (i.e. [`mmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)) rather than `read()`/`write()`. To avoid issues when mixed with calls to higher level functions, such as `scanf()`, `getchar()` is *forced* to use the same buffering structures.

Without information from a profiler, I'd worry more about the structural complexity of any code that uses `getchar()` than about any performance issues caused by its use.

Comment: It's impossible to use `mmap` to implement `FILE *`. The `mmap` support in glibc is only an option used if you pass non-standard flags to the `fopen` function. This is because file truncation after the map is created will result in `SIGBUS` when you try to access the part that no longer exists.

Comment: @R..: I edited my answer to make it more clear on this point - having bumped on the `SIGBUS` issue myself I should have paid more attention to that part...

Comment: Note that if the kernel added a new `mmap` flag to use an alternate signal in place of `SIGBUS`, and if that signal were in turn reserved for use by the userspace standard library implementation rather than the application (much like the internal signals used by pthreads), it would be possible to implement stdio buffers safely with `mmap`. However, I suspect the performance benefits would be very disappointing relative to all the effort that would go into making it possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple implementation.

```
int mygetchar(void)
{
        static char buf[BUFSIZ];
        static char *bufp = buf;
        static int i = 0;

        if (i == 0)
        {
                i = read(0, buf, 1);
                bufp = buf;
        }
        if ( --i >= 0 )
        {
                return  *bufp++;
        }

        return EOF;
}
```

Comment: There are 3 problems with this solution: (1) You don't need `buf` to be of size `BUFSIZ` (which btw requires `<stdio.h>`) because you call `read` with `1` as its third argument. (2) As Greg Hewgill [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544151/how-getchar-is-implemented#comment12094385_9544151) you need facilities for handling a pushback (of at least 1 character). (3) If `read` ever returns `0`, `--i` will cause it to become negative; thereafter your function will always return `EOF`. Whether this is as intended or not, `i` becoming ever more negative is a bug.