# How getchar() works internally?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, getchar

On my terminal, If I run,

```
> tty
/dev/tty0
> ./myprogram.out
```

where my program has `getchar()`, then it blocks on `stdin`(0) file descriptor that is waiting for input from `/dev/tty0` file.

This process is also scheduled by Process mgmt based on the time slice that it gets.

my question is,

How does `getchar()` wait on `stdin`? What is the system call that `getchar()` internally use for waiting for input on `stdin`?

Comment: Several questions that already touch on this.  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544151/how-getchar-is-implemented or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131873/equivalent-of-fgetc-with-unix-file-descriptors.

Comment: You can use `strace` to see all the system calls any program makes.

Comment: Matteo Italia's answer is probably as far down the rabbit hole as you want to go with this question. Any further, and you're [dealing with TTY stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRt4W.png).

Answer (score 4):

Most probably a plain blocking `read` over the FD associated with the C stream `stdin`, performed when the read buffer is empty.